# Sending messages from Azure IoT Device Twin to on premise terminal

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-digital-twins

I try to implement Azure IoT Device messaging between IoT Hub and repo in my local computer. I created IoT Hub, registered device, made certificates and sucessfully coupled it with Python codes in my repo. Now my code is sending messages to IoT HUB like this:

[image]

For every Azure ioT device has its device twin. I have to prepare the code that sucessfully show twin messages not only in Azure Hub in my local terminal.

I tried to configure Azure IoT device with tracing settings:

[image]

Also, I tried to implement several libraries and clases in my Python code:

```
from s7agent.common import LOG
from json import dumps as json_dumps
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message, X509
```

Further, it is not clear, how to configure Azure IoT device, what additional library or code part should I add in my local code to see Azure IoT twin message in Python terminal. Will appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When the Device Twin is updated in IoT Hub, a device is notified of the change if it has a connection (otherwise it can retrieve it next time it's online). In the Python SDK, to receive that message you have to set up a message handler. How to do that is shown in [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/async-hub-scenarios/receive_twin_desired_properties_patch.py)

> I have to prepare the code that sucessfully show twin messages not
> only in Azure Hub in my local terminal.

In that example, when the message comes in, it's printed to the terminal. That might be exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I found a lot of code samples there, and not sure if anything else is to be added except receive_twin_desired_properties_patch.py. Do I also need to make additional configuration of the twin to get messages to terminal?

Comment: A simple `print` should do show the output in the terminal. There are probably logging libraries as well. But this should suffice if you just need text on screen.

Comment: OK
what should I print out there: only the result of https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/tree/master/azure-iot-device/samples/async-hub-scenarios ?

Comment: I might be confused. Are you trying to print the twin update that your device is receiving? Or are you trying to write a program that prints updates for all devices?

Comment: Sorry,
resolved problem. I actually needed update message routing, switch IDE from Pycharm to Visual Studio Code, press "start monitoring Built In Event Endpoint" in VS Code, and inspect  the Outputs window. There I found my desired message from Hub